# java: package net.proteanit.sql does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, package

```
java: package net.proteanit.sql does not exist
```

I am getting this error in my project. I have seen the solution to this particular question here, but the solution is for Netbeans IDE and I am using IntelliJ Idea IDE. So, Please suggest a way to resolve this error in IntelliJ. It is very important so please answer it as soon as possible.

Comment: Please make sure that `net.proteanit.sql` dependency was added to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-a-module-library).

Comment: Please tell me how to add it in intelliJ

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ GUI do

`File -> Invalidate Caches /Restart`

Then
`Build -> Rebuild Project`

Comment: Hey brother, Thank you for your solution but I have clearly mentioned, that I am using IntelliJ IDE not Netbeans so I need the solution for IntelliJ

Comment: Changed for IntelliJ. Try it out and tell me if it works

Comment: It also not working